# React Native: Passing useState() data to unrelated screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, use-state, react-navigation-v5

**Explanation:** I am creating a fitness app, my fitness app has a component called WorkoutTimer that connects to the workout screen, and that screen is accessed via the HomeScreen. Inside the WorkoutTimer, I have an exerciseCount useState() that counts every time the timer does a complete loop (onto the next exercise). I have a different screen called StatsScreen which is accessed via the HomeScreen tab that I plan to display (and save) the number of exercises completed.

**What I've done:** I have quite literally spent all day researching around this, but it seems a bit harder with unrelated screens. I saw I might have to use useContext() but it seemed super difficult. I am fairly new to react native so I am trying my best haha! I have attached the code for each screen I think is needed, and attached a screenshot of my homeScreen tab so you can get a feel of how my application works.

**WorkoutTimer.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Button,
  Animated,
  Image,
  SafeAreaView,
} from "react-native";

import { CountdownCircleTimer } from "react-native-countdown-circle-timer";
import { Colors } from "../colors/Colors";

export default function WorkoutTimer() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  const [exerciseCount, setExerciseCount] = useState(0);
  const [workoutCount, setWorkoutCount] = useState(0);

  const exercise = new Array(21);
  exercise[1] = require("../assets/FR1.png");
  exercise[2] = require("../assets/FR2.png");
  exercise[3] = require("../assets/FR3.png");
  exercise[4] = require("../assets/FR4.png");
  exercise[5] = require("../assets/FR5.png");
  exercise[6] = require("../assets/FR6.png");
  exercise[7] = require("../assets/FR7.png");
  exercise[8] = require("../assets/FR8.png");
  exercise[9] = require("../assets/S1.png");
  exercise[10] = require("../assets/S2.png");
  exercise[11] = require("../assets/S3.png");
  exercise[12] = require("../assets/S4.png");
  exercise[13] = require("../assets/S5.png");
  exercise[14] = require("../assets/S6.png");
  exercise[15] = require("../assets/S7.png");
  exercise[16] = require("../assets/S8.png");
  exercise[17] = require("../assets/S9.png");
  exercise[18] = require("../assets/S10.png");
  exercise[19] = require("../assets/S11.png");
  exercise[20] = require("../assets/S12.png");
  exercise[21] = require("../assets/S13.png");

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.timerCont}>
        <CountdownCircleTimer
          isPlaying
          duration={45}
          size={240}
          colors={"#7B4FFF"}
          onComplete={() => {
            setCount((prevState) => prevState + 1);
            setExerciseCount((prevState) => prevState + 1);

            if (count == 21) {
              return [false, 0];
            }
            return [(true, 1000)]; // repeat animation for one second
          }}
        >
          {({ remainingTime, animatedColor }) => (
            <View>
              <Image
                source={exercise[count]}
                style={{
                  width: 150,
                  height: 150,
                }}
              />
              <View style={styles.timeOutside}>
                <Animated.Text
                  style={{
                    color: animatedColor,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    position: "absolute",
                    marginTop: 67,
                    marginLeft: 35,
                  }}
                >
                  {remainingTime}
                </Animated.Text>
                <Text style={styles.value}>seconds</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          )}
        </CountdownCircleTimer>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

**WorkoutScreen.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import WorkoutTimer from "../components/WorkoutTimer";

export default function WorkoutScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WorkoutTimer />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, Button } from "react-native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { AntDesign } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import { Colors } from "../colors/Colors";

export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.pageRef}>SUMMARY</Text>
      <Text style={styles.heading}>STRETCH & ROLL</Text>
      <View style={styles.content}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.timerDefault}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("WorkoutScreen")}
        >
          <Button title="START WORKOUT" color={Colors.primary} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.statContainer}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("StatsScreen")}
        >
          <AntDesign name="barschart" size={18} color={Colors.primary} />
          <Text style={{ color: Colors.primary }}>Statistics</Text>
          <AntDesign name="book" size={18} color={Colors.primary} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

**StatsScreen.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { exerciseCount, workoutCount } from "../components/WorkoutTimer";

export default function StatsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text display={exerciseCount} style={styles.exerciseText}>
        {exerciseCount}
      </Text>
      <Text display={workoutCount} style={styles.workoutText}>
        {workoutCount}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

[Home Screen Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBzPA.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're almost there! You're trying to get your 2 state
variables from the `WorkoutTimer` like this:

```js
import { exerciseCount, workoutCount } from "../components/WorkoutTimer";
```

Unfortunatly this won't work :( . These two variables change throughout your
App's life-time and that kinda [makes them "special"](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

In React, these kinds of variables need to be declared in a [parent component
and passed along to all children](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), which are interested in them.
So in your current Setup you have a parent child relationship like:

```
HomeScreen -> WorkoutScreen -> WorkoutTimer.
```

If you move the variables to HomeScreen (HomeScreen.js)

```
export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [exerciseCount, setExerciseCount] = useState(0);
  const [workoutCount, setWorkoutCount] = useState(0);
```

you can then pass them along to `WorkoutScreen` or `StatsScreen` with something
like:

```
navigation.navigate("WorkoutScreen", { exerciseCount })
navigation.navigate("StatsScreen", { exerciseCount })
```

You'll probably have to read up on react-navigation's documentation for `.navigate` I'm not sure I remember this correctly.

In order to read the variable you can then:

```js
  export default function WorkoutScreen({ navigation }) {
    const exerciseCount  = navigation.getParam(exerciseCount);

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <WorkoutTimer exerciseCount={exerciseCount} />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

and finally show it in the WorkoutTimer:

```
export default function WorkoutTimer({ exerciseCount }) {
```

Of course that's just part of the solution, since you'll also have to pass
along a way to update your variables (`setExerciseCount` and `setWorkoutCount`).

I encourage you to read through the links I posted and try to get this to work.
After you've accumulated a few of these stateful variables, you might also want to look at [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), but this is a bit much for now.

Your app looks cool, keep at it!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this problem with useContext if anyone is curious, it was hard to solve initially. But once I got my head around it, it wasn't too difficult to understand.

I created another file called exerciseContext with this code:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

const ExerciseContext = createContext([{}, () => {}]);

const ExerciseProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  //{ exerciseCount: 0, workoutCount: 0 }

  return (
    <ExerciseContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>
      {props.children}
    </ExerciseContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ExerciseContext, ExerciseProvider };
```

and in App.js I used ExerciseProvider which allowed me to pass the data over the screens.

```
  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <ExerciseProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <MyTabs />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </ExerciseProvider>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={getFonts} onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)} />
    );
  }
}
```

I could call it with:

```
import { ExerciseContext } from "../components/ExerciseContext";
```

and

```
const [exerciseCount, setExerciseCount] = useContext(ExerciseContext);
```

This meant I could change the state too! Boom, solved! If anyone needs an explanation, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use Mobx or Redux for state management. That will be more productive for you instead built-in state.